# Eclipse Build Issue in Dynamic Web Project Creation

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, web, build

I am tyring to build dynamic web application using Eclipse Luna and facing one very strange problem. When I build using eclipse there is no "classes" folder generated and hence application is not able to find the classes ie. the servlets. However if I build war file for my project, classes folder is generated and works perfectly fine.

I have searched the web on this issue and tried the possible solutions. Here are the screenshots of my project settings and few solutions that people recommended. Looks like I am missing either some important property or else eclipse is playing weird.

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Project Properties]

[image: Available Customizations]

[image: war structure]
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving this path in the output folder `Testing123/build/classes` instead of `Testing123/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: glad i was of help.. :)